# Find the inverse of a arcsin function

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

Trying to find the inverse of $$ 2*\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right) $$

My approach: $$ 2*\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right) = y \iff \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right) = \frac{y}{2}$$
$$ \iff \frac{1}{1+x} = \sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \iff 1+x= \frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)} \iff x = \frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)} - 1 $$

For domain and range of the inverse I have $$\mathbf {D} = \{x \in \Bbb {R}: -\pi \le x \le \pi\} $$
$$\mathbf {R} = \{y \in \Bbb {R}: -2 \le x \le 0, x\ne1\} $$

Checking the inverse and plot in Wolframalpha, it doesn't look at all like this. Is the problem here the multiplication by $(1+x)$ without knowing whether it is positive or negative? How to do this?

Comment: you did fine and i found the answer in wolfram alpha is the same as yours https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+function+2arcsin(1%2F(1%2Bx

Comment: Now I see they are the same - I must have done something wrong when graphing them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right and the problem you seem to have interpreting your answer is the following fact: consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$$ You have $f(-2)=-1$,  $f(0)=1$ and $|f(x)|\gt 1$ for $-2\lt x\lt 0$ hence arcosin $f(x)$ is not defined in this domain despite your answer-function it is (*actually the domain of your answer is all $\Bbb R$ excepting the points in which $\sin \frac y2=0$*)

Comment: Okay, I split the $\frac{1}{1+x}$ into different cases for $1+x\lt0$ and $1+x\gt0$ and managed to get the right answer for the domain of this function.

Comment: Well for $1+x\gt 0$ but $1+x\lt -1$ instead of $1+x\lt 0$ (I know it is, simply, a lapse Mine maybe?). Regards.